# ПОмогите избавиться от вложенного запроса SQL

Tags: sql, join

Помогите сделать один SQL без использования вложенности.
Есть таблица с авторизациями по токену юзера с его ip и таблица сессий всех userов. Нужно найти были ли у юзера который залогинился пересечения по сессиям с другими юзерами и сколько раз.

Есть **"TableToken"**:

| № | userIp | userId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 2 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 3 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 4 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 5 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |

и есть **"TableSession"**

| № | userIp | userId | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 180.15.0.1 | 222 | mail1@mail.ru |
| 2 | 180.15.0.1 | 555 | mail2@mail.ru |
| 3 | 180.15.0.1 | 333 | mail3@mail.ru |
| 4 | 190.15.0.1 | 777 | mail4@mail.ru |
| 5 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 | mail5@mail.ru |

Нужно одновременно вывести из "TableToken":

1. TableToken.userIp
2. Количество одинаковых userIp у userId = 111 (180.15.0.1 - 3 раза, 190.15.0.1 - 2 раза)
3. Общее количество разных UserIp (будет 2 как в примере)
4. Сколько пересечений в таблице "TableSession" по userIp у других userId (userId != 111).

**Ожидаемый результат** для наглядности:

| userIp | UserLoginCount | totalCount | matchesCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 180.15.0.1 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 190.15.0.1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Мой SQL запрос:

```
SELECT ts.userIp,
       tl.UserLoginCount,
       tl.totalCount,
       count(ts.userIp) matchesCount
FROM TableSession ts
JOIN ( SELECT userIp,
              userId,
              COUNT(*) UserLoginCount,
              COUNT(*) OVER () as totalCount
       FROM TableLogin
       WHERE userId = 111
       GROUP BY userIp ) tl USING (userIp)
WHERE ts.userId  <> tl.userId
GROUP BY ts.userIp;
```

Этот запрос с вложенность, возможно ли отказаться от вложенности?

P.S.: еще хотелось бы добавить вывод email тех пользователей с кем пересечение (т.к их может быть несколько, то один можно попробовать через CONCAT вывести в одной строке через запятую)

Comment: а что не так с вложенным запросом? Зачем избавляться?

Comment: Выложите исходные таблицы в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Или как ссылку на online fiddle. И укажите конкретную СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: *возможно ли отказаться от вложенности?* А зачем? подзапрос не correlated, не volatile...

Comment: Ссылка на таблицы которые мне уже помогли составить ранее https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2f225aa8f5af139ea43f1e6f5febca5
От вложенности избавляюсь потому что можем получить заполнение памяти бд 1000 записей первого селекта * 1000 записей второго селекта. Версия MySQL 8.0

Comment: @Robokop А что такое "Заполнение памяти БД" ? БД сама решит каким путем ей выполнять запрос смотря на наличие индексов на таблицах, статистики распределения данных и других факторов. Как это расположить в памяти она то же решит сама. Если посчитает, что результат выполнения подзапроса слишком большой и его невыгодно держать в памяти, то создаст временную таблицу на диске из его результатов. Или например поймет, что по userIp есть индекс и будет брать записи по одной из исходных таблиц.

Comment: @Robokop  Переделывать работающий запрос имеет смысл если он долго работает и вы по плану выполнения (explain) видите, что можно сделать лучше